# Angular 16 Material binding must be forced

Tags: angular-material, binding, angular16

I'm developing a solution Angular 16 Material using the free theme Matero.

I started from the downloadable demo so Angular Core ^16.2.7 etc.(https://github.com/ng-matero/ng-matero/blob/main/package.json), deleting the unuseful demo parts.

I'm facing a problem with subscribing after a http call, i need to declare

```
@Component({
  ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

in the constructor

```
export class LoginComponent {
  isSubmitting = false;
  ...
  constructor(
    ...
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {}
```

and finally after a call for example a login

```
    this.isSubmitting = true;
    this.auth
      .login(this.username.value, this.password.value, this.rememberMe.value)
      .pipe(filter(authenticated => authenticated))
      .subscribe({
        next: () => {
            this.isSubmitting = false; 
            this.ref.markForCheck();
        },
```

in the html for example a button

```
<button class="w-full m-y-16" mat-raised-button color="primary"
        [loading]="isSubmitting"
        (click)="login()">{{'login' | translate}}</button>
```

With the previous code, pratically it should happens nothing (there is no router redirection) but by clicking the button the spinner inside the button should cease to spin and appear back the "Login" text.

But this happens because the "this.ref.markForCheck();" otherwise without this call it ignores the change of isSubmitting and the spinner remain here.

The same for an http call ( normal call with HttpClient that returns an Observable) with binding to a mtx-grid, the binding succeed only by calling "this.ref.markForCheck();" in the "subscribe".

Angular CLI is 16.2.10

What i'm doing in a wrong manner ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/change-detection-skipping-subtrees#using-onpush) for `OnPush`.

> OnPush change detection instructs Angular to run change detection for a component subtree only when:

> 1. The root component of the subtree receives new inputs as the result of a template binding. Angular compares the current and past value of the input with ==
> 2. Angular handles an event (for example using event binding, output binding, or @HostListener ) in the subtree's root component or any of its children whether they are using OnPush change detection or not.

Since in your scenario, both of these scenarios do not qualify for change detection to run, hence you need to do either `markForCheck` or `detectChanges`, to trigger the change detection to get the desired output!

You can either remove `OnPush` change detection or you can trigger `markForCheck` wherever needed.

OnPush is more effecient than normal change detection strategy, since change detection runs less, but you need to handle all cases where change detection needs to run, its usually done on large FE load components, to improve performance!

Comment: In the past Angular projects except an Angular 8 some years ago, i always developed sites using Bootstrap since Angular 2 to 12: never needed this forced acknowledge.
I don't understand but i will use always this trick, then.

Comment: @RobertoAlessi This line `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` is why we need to trigger change detection

Comment: @RobertoAlessi If default change detection strategy is set, there is no need to do `markForCheck` since angular handles that internally! that is only needed for onPush change detection strategy

Comment: ok @NarenMurali, but if i delete this line and then the markforcheck the binding is not working at all, already in the simple button case where it remains the spinner. By changing (or deleting at all) the strategy as ```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
``` declaring the variable as ``` isSubmitting = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); cast = this.isSubmitting.asObservable(); ``` using in code as
```
this.isSubmitting.next(true) ; // or false
``` in the html
```
[loading]="cast | async"
``` it works, but it seems all so overcomplicated